# Nested IF(AND) statement with too many arguments in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to work return a boolean on whether the input number(Z8) will be allowed promotion based on whether it exceeds a certain threshold based on the grading. Excel has said that my function has too many arguments, but I've cross-checked it with other users and seems like my syntax is correct.

My code is below:

```
=IF(AND(F8="Non-Clerical", Z8>=250), "YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="C", Z8>=350), "YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="SC", Z8>=500), "YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="S", Z8>=550), "YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="SS", Z8>=650, "YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="SG1",, Z8>=700), "YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="SG2", Z8>=750), "YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="SG3", Z8>=800), "YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="SG4", Z8>=850), "YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="M1", Z8>=950), "YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="M2", Z8>=1100), "YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="M3", Z8>=1400),"YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="M4",Z8>=1800), "YES", "NO", IF(F8="M5",Z8>=2500), "YES", "NO", IF(AND(F8="M6", Z8>=5000, "YES", "NO")))))))))))))))
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: remove all the `,"NO"` but the last one.

Comment: @scottcraner, I tried it but it didn't work. It still says that there are too many arguments. Hmmm.

Comment: you will need show the new formula.

Comment: @scottcraner ``` =IF(AND(F8="Non-Clerical", Z8>=250), "YES", IF(AND(F8="C", Z8>=350), "YES", IF(AND(F8="SC", Z8>=500), "YES", IF(AND(F8="S", Z8>=550), "YES", IF(AND(F8="SS", Z8>=650, "YES", IF(AND(F8="SG1",, Z8>=700), "YES", IF(AND(F8="SG2", Z8>=750), "YES", IF(AND(F8="SG3", Z8>=800), "YES", IF(AND(F8="SG4", Z8>=850), "YES", IF(AND(F8="M1", Z8>=950), "YES", IF(AND(F8="M2", Z8>=1100), "YES", IF(AND(F8="M3", Z8>=1400),"YES", IF(AND(F8="M4",Z8>=1800), "YES", IF(F8="M5",Z8>=2500), "YES", IF(AND(F8="M6", Z8>=5000, "YES", "NO"))))))))))))))) ```

Comment: Your `)` are off: `=IF(AND(F8="Non-Clerical", Z8>=250), "YES", IF(AND(F8="C", Z8>=350), "YES",IF(AND(F8="SC", Z8>=500), "YES",IF(AND(F8="S", Z8>=550), "YES",IF(AND(F8="SS", Z8>=650), "YES",IF(AND(F8="SG1",Z8>=700), "YES",IF(AND(F8="SG2", Z8>=750), "YES",IF(AND(F8="SG3", Z8>=800), "YES",IF(AND(F8="SG4", Z8>=850), "YES",IF(AND(F8="M1", Z8>=950), "YES",IF(AND(F8="M2", Z8>=1100), "YES",IF(AND(F8="M3", Z8>=1400),"YES",IF(AND(F8="M4",Z8>=1800), "YES",IF(AND(F8="M5",Z8>=2500), "YES",IF(AND(F8="M6", Z8>=5000), "YES", "NO")))))))))))))))`

Comment: @scottcraner, that works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

After removing the `"NO"` portions that Scott Craner points out, and fixing the three errors that come when doing in-depth formulas composed on the fly (two `)` and an `AND()`), one could change the approach of the formula a small bit (though lots of typing to delete bits to do it) to the following:

```
=  
IF(  
OR(  
AND(F8="Non-Clerical",Z8>=250),  
AND(F8="C",Z8>=350),  
AND(F8="SC",Z8>=500),  
AND(F8="S",Z8>=550),  
AND(F8="SS",Z8>=650),  
AND(F8="SG1",,Z8>=700), (see below, near end about this line)  
AND(F8="SG2",Z8>=750),  
AND(F8="SG3",Z8>=800),  
AND(F8="SG4",Z8>=850),  
AND(F8="M1",Z8>=950),  
AND(F8="M2",Z8>=1100),  
AND(F8="M3",Z8>=1400),  
AND(F8="M4",Z8>=1800),  
AND(F8="M5",Z8>=2500),  
AND(F8="M6",Z8>=5000)  
),  
"YES","NO")
```

The idea is that since each of those `AND()` conditions generated the same `YES`, collecting them as shown, in an `OR()`, would accomplish the same, but leave things much clearer to anyone looking at it. Now, or in the future.
But to really make the idea sing, structure it physically like above with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to keep shifting down lines. Then the clauses are all as close to being in a column with  each other as possible making structure differences like forgetting an `AND()` or a `)` easy to spot, if missed, but even better, hard to miss to begin with. One could even structure it by copying something like:

```
AND(F8="",Z8>=),
```

and pasting it to however lines one needs, then filling in the two conditions after building the structure.

As animals, we are "difference machines":  we spot differences supremely well. Motion, especially, as that is sort of an ultra-difference, but wouldn't help here, of course! It is often said we are "pattern machine", but spotting a pattern is just the second level analysis based upon spotting differences to begin with. "Just" might be unfair as that analysis has fed a lot of humans over the milennia, but...

Anyway, doing it like this matters not to Excel and gives you a chance to use your human strengths. "Work harder not..." no, wait, I have it now:  `Work SMARTER, not harder!`

Emphasizing this, the difference catching brought up an error that was not addressed by anyone. In the 6th `AND()` clause, above, there is an extra comma:

```
AND(F8="SG1",,Z8>=700),  
........................^^
```

between the first and second clauses in the `AND()` (I left it in the above so one can see how it stands out structured like this). It would cause that clause to fail since an empty clause returns `FALSE` in an `AND()`. In-depth formulating like the example given is very prone to this kind of error, one that is very subtle, yet not trapped by Excel (How would it know it is a mistake? Even though it maybe ought to ask, there is some practical stopping point to the nannying and MS apparently decided that point was before considering this kind of thing.) but likely would lead to hugely vexing troubleshooting.

AFTER it was realized there was something to troubleshoot. Which might be 12 years later.

Few people write something like this formula and then set up cases that accurately and at the minimum, explicitly, test each clause. Usually if it seems to work, it is considered to work...

Comment: That's a very detailed answer @Jeorje, thank you for your detailed answer and keen eye. Cheers.